# Call PHP Function from String where the string is the class member and the function exists globally

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project where $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] is formatted and then used to call a globally defined function. Essentially, the function below works correctly: when I call URIHandle() in my index.php and load "index.php/hello" in browser, the globally defined function "hello" is called.

```
  function URIHandle(){
    $uri = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];
    $uri = ltrim($uri,"/");
    $uri = rtrim($uri,"/"); 
    try{
        if(isset($uri))
            echo $uri();
        else
            echo UserHome();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        http_response_code(404); 
    }
}
```

I wanted this to fit in with the rest of my code so wrapped it up in a class:

```
class URIHandler{
    function __construct(){
        $this->uri = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];
        $this->Prepare();
    }

    function Prepare(){
        $this->uri = ltrim($this->uri,"/");
        $this->uri = rtrim($this->uri,"/");
    }

    public function Handle(){
        try{
            if(isset($this->uri)){
                echo $this->uri();
            }
            else
                echo UserHome();
        } catch(Exception $e){
            http_response_code(404);
        }
    }
}
```

If I instantiate this class and call Handle(), the globally defined method "hello" is not called. As far as I'm concerned, these 2 functions should functionally be the same.

Comment: `echo $this->uri();` its not a method so it should be `echo $this->uri;`

Comment: Thanks iDontDownVote, however if I have a function (function hello), and then I allocate a string var ($strHello = "hello"), and then call $strHello(), the function hello will be called. 

The accepted answer uses the function, call_user_func, which seems to have the intended effect when called from within the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to do this is to use the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function.

```
class URIHandler{
    function __construct(){
        $this->uri = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];
        $this->Prepare();
    }

    function Prepare(){
        $this->uri = ltrim($this->uri,"/");
        $this->uri = rtrim($this->uri,"/");
    }

    public function Handle(){
        try{
            if(isset($this->uri)){
                echo call_user_func($this->uri);
            }
            else
                echo UserHome();
        } catch(Exception $e){
            http_response_code(404);
        }
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove the specified character from both the beginning and end of a given string.

```
$this->uri = ltrim($this->uri,"/");
$this->uri = rtrim($this->uri,"/");

// or

$this->uri = trim($this->uri, '/');
```